# How to aggregate by one column to build rows while aggregation in other columns transforms into new columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I am rather new to R and I am still unable to solve a certain aggregation problem; I have information of this form:

```
SubjectType   Subtype
---------------------
TypeA            1
TypeB            2
TypeC            1
TypeB            1
TypeA            1
```

And I want to transform this into the following form:

```
SubjectType   #(Subtype=1)  #(Subtype=2)
---------------------------------------- 
TypeA              2             0
TypeB              1             1
TypeC              1             0
```

I tried to achieve this by using the aggregate-function but I failed so far.
Can this even be done with a single aggregate(...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved what I was looking for by using the library dplyr.

```
library(dplyr);

subtype1 <- myData %>% group_by(myData$SubjectType) %>% summarize(subtype1 = sum(Subtype==1));
subtype2 <- myData %>% group_by(myData$SubjectType) %>% summarize(subtype1 = sum(Subtype==2));

merge(subtype1, subtype2);
```